# ¿Que preguntas debería contestar un candidato a moderador?

Tags: discusión, elecciones

Aclaro que aun nadie llamó a elecciones, no me consta tal cosa. Pero, a forma de ejercicio, quiero recopilar cuáles preguntas le harían ustedes a un candidato a moderador antes de decidir sus tres votos.

Claro que las respuestas no van aquí, solo las preguntas: ejemplo:

#### ¿Que harías si encuentras una pregunta cerrada, pero piensas que debería estar abierta?

Para los que no lo saben, esto es usual en las elecciones, armar una lista de preguntas que los precandidatos deben responder para acceder a la candidatura.

Tratemos de sacar las preguntas de las experiencia de nuestra comunidad y no vayamos a copiar esas preguntas que ya se han hecho una y otra vez en otras comunidades.

Comment: Ejemplos: [Fall 2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310356/1065197), [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290096/1065197](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290096/1065197), [2014 SO Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299969/1065197),

Answer (score 2):

#### ¿Actuarías de moderador en una pregunta/respuesta que necesita moderación en que has participado anteriormente en calidad de usuario normal?

Answer (score 2):

Algunas que estuve pensando durante estos días:

#### ¿Eliminarías una pregunta que sabes que es técnicamente incorrecta?

#### ¿Qué harías si ves que un usuario publica muchas preguntas que son cerradas?

#### ¿Cómo actuarías si encuentras que un usuario siempre vota negativo a otro usuario a propósito, inclusive si sus publicaciones son de calidad?

#### ¿Qué acción merece una respuesta con información correcta e interesante pero que no responde la pregunta principal?

#### ¿Cómo atenderías una respuesta reportada como spam donde el usuario promociona un producto sobre el que él trabaja y brinda mantenimiento?

Comment: Una pregunta , los botos son anonimos, tambien para los moderadores cierto?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a un proceso de votación? Siempre he pensado que sí.

Comment: Lo escribi desde el telefono no me di cuenta que decia "botos", me referia a los votos, que siempre han sido anonimos, si los moderadores pueden ver quienes han votado en una pregunta/respuesta.