# Sobre la elección de moderadores

Tags: discusión, moderadores, elecciones

Leyendo [dos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1129/) [preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/803/) sobre la elección de moderadores, me quedan algunas dudas, que expongo a continuación.

### Sobre el proceso de elección

1. ¿Podemos proponer o *nominar* a un tercero? Ej.: *Propongo a fulanito para moderador*. Y como ya lo propuse, ahora puede ser votado.
2. <strike>Puede haber o habrá *"periodo de campañas"* donde los candidatos se presenten y promuevan. No vaya a ser que los conozcamos el día de la primera ronda (si entendí bien, hay una primera ronda).</strike> Aunque es muy clara, la respuesta está [en inglés](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/).
3. Se permitirá la promoción del voto en el chat (porque por otros medios y redes no es posible el control, si acaso el monitoreo).

### Sobre las características de un moderador

Hay un [publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/803/) donde se propusieron una serie de preguntas que debía contestar un moderador. Y me parece un buen comienzo pero para mi, que no tengo experiencia en la red SE, no me queda claro **que es lo que se pretende descubrir *o demostrar* con las preguntas**.

Por ejemplo: *¿Que harías si encuentras una pregunta cerrada, pero piensas que debería estar abierta?*. ¿Hay un criterio estándar y los moderadores deben conocer y dominar este estándar?

Y entonces pienso que hay un conjunto de características que debe tener un moderador y que los usuarios **debemos aprender a apreciar**, pero no me quedan claro cuáles son. Por ejemplo:

1. **Conocimiento de las reglas**: El moderador debe demostrar el conocimiento de las reglas de moderación y aplicarlas adecuadamente. Y entonces hacemos preguntas como:

   - ¿Que harías si encuentras una pregunta cerrada, pero piensas que debería estar abierta?
   - ¿Qué acción merece una respuesta con información correcta e interesante pero que no responde la pregunta principal?
   - ¿Eliminarías una pregunta que sabes que es técnicamente incorrecta?
   - ¿Qué harías si ves que un usuario publica muchas preguntas que son cerradas?
2. **Imparcialidad**. Las decisiones de un moderador deben objetivas y sin sesgos. Preguntas como esta nos podrían ayudar:

   - ¿Actuarías de moderador en una pregunta/respuesta que necesita moderación en que has participado anteriormente en calidad de usuario normal?

Supongo que hay otras características que debe tener un moderador, pero no se me ocurre ninguna. Tal vez objetividad, pero puedo confundir este concepto con imparcialidad. NPI.

La pregunta es la siguiente:

### ¿Qué debo tener en consideración para tomar una decisión informada cuando llegue el momento de elegir a los moderadores?

¿Qué debería buscar en un moderador? ¿Qué nos conviene mas? ¿En qué deberíamos basar nuestra decisión?

- ¿Un moderador que sepa aplicar las reglas, únicamente?
- ¿Un moderador experto en algún lenguaje para que se imponga en las batallas de su tribu?
- ¿Un moderador que sea comprensivo y tolerante para guiar a los nuevos de forma didáctica?
- ¿Un moderador *cool* que se lleve bien con todos?

Comment: mmm.. es un sistema democrático, donde cada uno maneja sus propios criterios al votar. La encuesta que mencionas, (mas bien las respuestas dadas por cada candidato) debería ayudarte a tomar la decision pues funciona como una _plataforma electoral_.

Comment: Las decisiones son subjetivas, como comenta Emanuel, cada persona tiene su criterio, considero que el enfoque nuestro debe estar sobre las propuestas de quienes deseen proponerse como candidatos.

Comment: No, no se pueden proponer moderadores. Tienen que presentarse ellos mismos. Lo cual no impide que en el chat o por otros medios se pueda animar a alguien a presentarse. Pero en el hilo de nominaciones solo se admiten las hechas en primera persona (Anyone may nominate themselves to be a moderator as long as they fulfill certain conditions). @EmanuelVe SOes no es una democracia y las elecciones a moderador tampoco son democráticas. Y tampoco hace falta que lo sean, probablemente empeoraría si lo fuesen.

Comment: Pueden ver [esta publicación en el blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/30/ya-nos-graduamos-ahora-que-sigue/) para más información sobre esto.